# Windows 10 INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, bcd

I have moved my system partition to create 150 MB of space that I will later allocate to the boot partition.

Due to this now whenever I try to boot I get the BSOD of INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

I have tried the basic troubleshooting of [recreating](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/) the BCD from the command line from the recovery. Is there anything else I can do ?

I don't want to make a clean install since my Windows OS contains files I need.

Comment: What exactly did you do to move the partition? Do you actually boot using UEFI?

Comment: Why did you move this partition without understanding that it would effect your ability to boot to your Windows installation?

Comment: @Ramhound I moved the partition so that I can install Grub to the EFI partition after installing linux for dual boot purposes. The EFI partition did not have enough space so I had to first move the Windows partition and then add the free space to the EFI system partition.

Comment: @DanielB No idea. Any way to check ? But I know I am not using Secure Boot

Comment: You may boot up with Linux live CD and move all essential files to another partition. Then reinstall Windows OS.

Comment: @Biswa So there is no other way than a format ?

Comment: @Biswa No that is not the only way. I have been able to boot my device following the instructions in the Technet article in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using the instructions given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx).